Retrieving block-membership in graph-tool
I am wondering if there is an efficient way to retrieve the block membership of a node (or all the nodes that belong to a block) with a NestedBlockModel object, as my current approach needs to iterate over all levels and nodes. Here is my current code:
memberships = {}
levels = state.get_levels()

for v in g.vertices():
    memberships[g.vp['name'][v]] = []
    for level in range(len(levels)):
        r = levels[level].get_blocks()[v]
        memberships[g.vp['name'][v]].append(r)

for level in range(len(state.levels)):
    print ('LEVEL: %s'%level)
    bg = state.levels[level].get_bg()
    state.levels[level]

    # Print groups
    nauth, gsize = 0, []
    for ngroup in range(max([memberships[au][level] for au in memberships])):
        authors = [au for au in memberships if memberships[au][level] == ngroup]
        nauth += len(authors)
        gsize.append(len(authors))
        if authors != []:
            print ('> Group %d-%d (%d):\t%s' % (level, ngroup, len(authors), ', '.join(authors)))
    print ('> TOTAL: %d authors' % nauth)

and why 'levels[level].get_blocks()[v]' gives you an answer if you manually set v >> n_vertices?
I am also wondering what happens with all these empty nodes retrieved by the inference (til the 5ht level) and all those levels with just 1 block.
 <BlockState object with 1580 blocks (94 nonempty)
 <BlockState object with 65 blocks (14 nonempty)
 <BlockState object with 13 blocks (5 nonempty)
 <BlockState object with 6 blocks (2 nonempty)
 <BlockState object with 3 blocks (1 nonempty)
 <BlockState object with 2 blocks (1 nonempty)
 <BlockState object with 1 blocks (1 nonempty)
 <BlockState object with 1 blocks (1 nonempty)
 <BlockState object with 1 blocks (1 nonempty)
 <BlockState object with 1 blocks (1 nonempty)
 <BlockState object with 1 blocks (1 nonempty)
 <BlockState object with 1 blocks (1 nonempty)

